# Symmetric matrix is bijective on its range

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I came across the following question.
Let $A$ be a symmetric real matrix. Then I know this means that $A$ is self adjoint with respect to the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that $A$ is then an isomorphism on its range $R(A)$?
Clearly $A$ is linear and $$
A: R(A) \rightarrow R(A)
$$ (i.e. the image of the range of $A$ under $A$ itself is contained in the range of $A$). I only need to prove that it is a bijection.
I tried to solve
$$
AAw = Av
$$
and show there is a unique solution $w$ but could not do it.
Is there a way to see this? Does this follow from some more general functional analysis fact about self adjoint operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric, $A$ is diagonalizable. Let $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues with eigenvectors $v_1, \cdots, v_n$ respectively. Assume that $\lambda_1, \cdots \lambda_k \neq 0$ and $\lambda_{k+1}, \cdots , \lambda_n = 0$. ($k$ might be $n$)

Then $R(A) = \operatorname{span}\{ v_i: i=1, \cdots, k\}$ and when restricted to this subspace,

$$A(c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_k v_k) = c_1 \lambda _1 v_1 + \cdots + c_k\lambda_kv_k$$

maps into $R(A)$ and has inverse

$$c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_k v_k\mapsto c_1 \lambda^{-1}_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_k \lambda^{-1}_k v_k.$$

Thus $A: R(A) \to R(A)$ is bijective.